# Find the number of people, average of age

Tags: average

The average age of a group of persons going for a picnic is $16.75$ years. $20$ new persons with
an average age of $13.25$ years join the group on the spot due to which the average of the group becomes $15$ years. Find the number of persons initially going for the picnic.

I assumed
number of people in initial group to be $x$ and $$avg.age(x group)=16.75 years$$
number of people in addition to be $y$ which will be $20$ and $$avg.age(y group)=13.25 years$$

Now the groups are added let that be $x+y$ and $avg.age(x+y)=15years$
We do know that sum of all the quantities in a list by number of quantities will give us the average.
I took the sum of average of both the groups which is 15

$$(avg.age(x)+avg.age(y))/(20+x)=15$$
then $$x=18$$ which is a wrong answer.

Please provide me with right solution and explanation.

Comment: You have a system of 3 eqs with three unknown: $\dfrac {a_1}{n}=16.75$ and $\dfrac {a_2}{20}=13.25$ and $\dfrac {a_1+a_2}{n+20}=15$ where $a_1$ is the sum of the ages of the elements of the first group, $a_2$ the same for the second one and $n$ is the (unknown) number of elements of the first group.

Comment: IMO the result will be $n=20$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the original amount of people be $x$, so there are $x+20$ people in the end. Then the total age of all the people will be $16.75x+13.25\times20$, so the average of ages of all the people is

\begin{align}
\frac{16.75x+265}{x+20}&=15\\
16.75x+265&=15(x+20)\\
16.75x+265&=15x+300\\
1.75x&=35\\
0.25x&=5\\
x&=20
\end{align}

Therefore, there are originally $20$ people at the picnic.